# Bootstrap Products horizontally like eCommerce store

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want my Products horizontally like in the attached image but when i add products in my page it shows in vertical format but i want horizontal like attached like eCommerce product page [picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2wkZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

All you need to set correct grid structure of bootstrap here

Based on your picture there needs to set the grids of 3 columns. 
You can get idea for this from bootstrap official website: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid

Here is the basic code for the grids, which you can modify further.

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">1st Grid</div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">2nd Grid</div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">3rd Grid</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but in my case i have only one div on which for-each loop iterates

Comment: @Ali Shan, You can set these grids with for-each loops. All you need to set one additional class here by which you can define additional styles for cards/grids like borders, shadows, etc.